# ST_Intersection for polygons

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, polygon, intersection

I'm looking for a query that returns overlapping areas of two tables with polygon geometries. Using row_number() over() the entries of the gid column are not unique in the case of dumped multipolygons. So I get some troubles when loading the layer into QGIS.

```
CREATE TABLE poly_intersection AS
SELECT
row_number() over() AS gid,
(ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(poly1.geom, poly2.geom))).geom::geometry(polygon, SRID) AS geom
 FROM poly1, poly2
 WHERE ST_Overlaps(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) = 't' OR ST_Contains(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) = 't' OR ST_Contains(poly2.geom, poly1.geom) = 't';
```

Meanwhile I've modified my query. But I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

```
CREATE TABLE poly_intersection AS
SELECT
row_number() over() AS gid,
g.geom::geometry(polygon, SRID) AS geom
FROM
(SELECT
(ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(poly1.geom, poly2.geom))).geom
FROM
poly1, poly2
WHERE
ST_Overlaps(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) = 't' OR ST_Contains(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) = 't' OR ST_Contains(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) = 't')
AS g;
```

Comment: Also, you can use (ST_Dump(....).path to get unique IDs, though there is nothing wrong with using row_number() over(). While there is a difference between ST_Covers and ST_Contains, in this case I'm not sure it makes any difference. And, you only want polygons that are fully contained, as you say overlapping, but seem to be including ST_Intersects, which would return all polygons from ST_Contains in both directions.

Comment: I need all types of polygon intersections. AS far as I know ST_Intersects is TRUE for touching polygons too. ST_Intersection is returning linestrings or points in this case.

Comment: True. You can use WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom);

Comment: Thank you, I've to test if this improves the performance of my query.

Comment: Another option for encoding these relationship is to use [ST_Relate](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html) and an intersection matrix.

Comment: It seems that "ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)" is the fastest way to drop linestrings and points. But is there an option for generation unique gids without using a subquery? –

Comment: Yes, by using (ST_Dump(...)).* in sub query, which will then return you the path (which is the same as row_number() over() in the outer query). Put it as an answer, as it is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ST_Intersects combined with NOT ST_Touches will produce what you are looking for more efficiently, than two version of ST_Contains and ST_Covers. You can avoid row_number() over() to generate the gid if you select (ST_Dump(....)).* in the subquery and then select g.path and g.geom from that query.

```
CREATE TABLE poly_intersection AS
SELECT
  g.path[1] as gid,
  g.geom::geometry(polygon, SRID) AS geom
FROM
(SELECT
   (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(poly1.geom, poly2.geom))).*
FROM
  poly1, poly2
WHERE ST_Intersects(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) AND NOT ST_Touches(poly1.geom, poly2.geom) as g;
```

Comment: This does the job. Most likely there is no solution without any subquery.